# When should I use `REQUIRED` vs `NOT_SUPPORTED` as a the value of @TransactionAttribute for an MDB?

Tags: java, transactions, jms, ejb-3.0, jta

I know about container managed transactions(CMT). I also know about the [different possible values](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TransactionAttributeType.html) of the enumerated type `TransactionAttributeType`. Since the client never calls a MDB directly, the attribute types other than  the `REQUIRED` and `NOT_SUPPORTED` do not make sense for MDB's as there is no client initiated transaction to join to. So when should I annotate the `onMessage()` method of an MDB with  `REQUIRED` vs `NOT_SUPPORTED`? What will be the default behavior in none of the two options is mentioned?

Answer (score 6):

> What will be the default behavior in none of the two options is
>   mentioned?

The default behavior for `Container`-managed MDBs is `NOT_SUPPORTED`.

> So when should I annotate the onMessage() method of an MDB with
>   REQUIRED vs NOT_SUPPORTED?

Using NOT_SUPPORTED means - if a failure occurs in `onMessage()` - any updates/operations that occurred prior to the failure will not be rolled back; this is undesirable for atomic operations involving disparate resources.

If you don't want that behavior, use `REQUIRED`, put a try/catch in `onMessage()`, and call `setRollbackOnly()` in catch() when any exceptions occur. You will need XA drivers if `onMessage()` is performing multiple operations across different resources; for instance, updating a database and sending a new JMS message in the same transaction will most certainly require XA compatible drivers.

**MDB's support only REQUIRED or NOT_SUPPORTED**

MDB's may use `REQUIRED` or `NOT_SUPPORTED` transaction attributes; other attributes don't make sense since they require client context.

The container always starts a new transaction before calling `onMessage()`. If another method is called from `onMessage()`, the container passes along the current transaction context.

Comment: I have a follow up question. So before the `onMessage(..)` method is called, do the container create a transaction always? In that case setting the REQUIRED attribute will just join the container started transaction? Also why is the default behavior `NOT_SUPPORTED`. It seems like the default should be `SUPPORTED`.

Comment: Updated answer, raffian

Comment: can you please answer why the default behavior is NOT_SUPPORTED?

Answer (score 1):

I'm interested at this discussion. I was convinced that specs indicates that default transaction attribute is REQUIRED.

Some guys in another stackoverflow discussion :

[What is the default TRANSACTION ATTRIBUTE for MDBS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33344117/what-is-the-default-transaction-attribute-for-mdbs)

spoke about exception on Weblogic server implementation.