# What is the default TRANSACTION ATTRIBUTE for MDBS?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, transactions, ejb-3.0, weblogic-10.x

First of all I'am talking about EJB 3.

Second, I know that the question may seem too obvious as in the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TransactionAttribute.html) regarding the annotation `@TransactionAttribute`, it's clearly said (without any specification regarding if it's session beans or MDBs) that:

> **value**
>
> public abstract TransactionAttributeType value
>
> **Default:**
>
> ```
>     javax.ejb.TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED
> ```

But, I had this question in mind when I passed across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24123435/4170582). So, I tried to verify Its correctness and find if there is any other resources saying that. Thus, I found this note from the [Oracle Weblogic Server's docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/ejb/message_beans.html) :

> **Note:**     If transaction-type is set to Container, and trans-attribute is
>   not set, the default transaction-attribute value (NotSupported for
>   MDBs) is applied.

The question is this only specific to Weblogic servers? shouldn't they respect the specs? Or, I'm just missing an episode?

Comment: WLS always must respect the specs, and it may add new features, but not change the standard.

Comment: @Tarik I am also confused by this statement in the docs.  The EJB spec is clear that the default transaction attribute must be Required if unspecified.

Comment: @bkail, Yes I agree with you, but I still hope to hear something from a weblogic expert or someone who already tried that in a real application

Comment: Looks like it doesn't follow the specs. Since point `3.10 Transactions` of the EJB3.1 specification, clearly states: `The REQUIRED transaction attribute, is the default for the onMessage() method`